# Uniqueness constraint based on column value in a related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, let's call it `users` and `groups`. Some groups are by design singletons and must have exactly one user, and some groups can have multiple users.

```
users (
  id
)

groups (
  id
  name
  singleton
)

users_groups (
  user_id
  group_id
)
```

Is there a way to enforce the uniqueness constraint that would

- disallow adding more than one user to singleton groups
- remove singleton groups when its only user is deleted

Comment: Handling both these requirements is probably best accomplished with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Using triggers we can achieve these conditions.

There is another option , that would be to implement the functionality for "insert" and "delete" operations into stored procedures which would also check and remove singleton groups when its only user is deleted and also prevent addition of more than one user to the singleton groups